# relect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Using swagger codegen I generated a typescript-angular project and then built it by running npm install. I then wrote a test class and ran tsc to compile it to javascript so that I could run the test class using node. When I tried running the node testing.js command I received the error message "reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators." As the is not meant to be a full app I do not have an index.ts or main.ts files and as such other solutions that I came across (such as imports) are not working. When I run npm list I see that I do have reflect metadata in my node modules. Here is my tsconfig file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "noLib": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ]
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
],
"filesGlob": [
    "./model/*.ts",
    "./api/*.ts"
]
}
```

Is there a way to run a js file from node when it has decorators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So seems like I found a workable solution. I added

```
import "reflect-metadata"
```

to the first line of the typescript file (It had to be the first line as otherwise it was using decorators before the import had been done).